# How to send email with AAD Graph API with personal outlook account

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, console-application

Im trying to have a console application that will read my personal outlook account set as scheduled task, I have setup an AAD account with personal outlook account.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
try
        {

            string tenantId = "xxxxxx";
            string clientId = "xxxxxxxx";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx";
            string userId = "xxxxxxxxx";
            //The following scope is required to acquire the token
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);


            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Your subject here",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "Email Content"
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "xxxx@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            },
                CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "xxxxxx@email.com"
                    }
                }
            }
            };

          
            Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail
            .SendMailPostRequestBody requestbody = new()
            {
                Message = message,
                SaveToSentItems = false // or true, as you want
            };

            var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(user.Id + ": " + user.DisplayName + " <" + user.Mail + ">" + user.MailboxSettings);

            await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
                .SendMail
                .PostAsync(requestbody);

            //await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
            //      .SendMail(message, false)
            //      .Request()
            //      .PostAsync();

        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);

        }
```

The call to API was successful as I have manage to retrieve the user.Id which is my userobjectId, and my user name, but the mail is null, the error was no ResourcesNotFound, Resource could not be discovered.

I have did some research, it seems I need to assign license of 356 office in AAD to this outlook account in order to have the mailbox and the sendMail will work. But I'm a little but overwhelming by the information that I found online and not sure which is the correct approach.

Any advice or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to assign O365 license to the user and change auth provider to **Delegated** flow like interactive flow, auth code flow, username password flow etc....

Comment: @Sridevi thanks for the comment sir, I understand the part that required a 365 license so I will have a mailbox associated to the sender that I want to use, but for the delegated flow, from what I have learned from, since I'm running a console application that will have no user interaction within the process, the application permission is what I need to utilize here. Could you please provide a little more info or link for the resources that help me to correct my concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned `O365 license` to the user invited with personal Outlook account like below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I got **same error** even after assigning `O365 license` to the user:

```cs
try
        {

            string tenantId = "xxxxxx";
            string clientId = "xxxxxxxx";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx";
            string userId = "xxxxxxxxx";
            //The following scope is required to acquire the token
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);


            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Your subject here",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "Email Content"
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "xxxx@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            },
                CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            }
            };

          
            Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail
            .SendMailPostRequestBody requestbody = new()
            {
                Message = message,
                SaveToSentItems = false // or true, as you want
            };

            var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(user.Id + ": " + user.DisplayName + " <" + user.Mail + ">" + user.MailboxSettings);

            await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
                .SendMail
                .PostAsync(requestbody);

            //await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
            //      .SendMail(message, false)
            //      .Request()
            //      .PostAsync();

        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);

        }
```

**Response**

[image]

> As mentioned in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions:%7E:text=Delegated%20%28personal%20Microsoft%20account%29), personal Microsoft account requires `Mail.Send` **Delegated** permission that won't work with client credentials flow.

Without user interaction, you **cannot** send mail with personal Outlook account using client credentials flow by adding **Application** permission.

To resolve the issue, you must use **[delegated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#interactive-provider)** flow that involves user interaction like authorization code flow, interactive flow, etc....

Alternatively, you can also sign into [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with Outlook account that works with **Delegated** permissions and run below query to send mail:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxxx@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxxx@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Outlook `Sent Items`, email sent successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was trying to set up a scheduled console application that has no user interaction, delegated auth flow seems required user interaction to authorize which will not work in my scenario. Can I assume that if now the sender that I'm using is not a personal Microsoft account, instead it is a added user in AAD, and the admin has grant me the consent for mail.send API and assign a 365 to me. Then the code that using the application type permission with client credentials flow will work? Once again, thanks for your time and effort for helping out.

Comment: Yes, if it is local Azure AD user with O365 license then the code using the application type `Mail.Send` permission with client credentials flow will work.