# How do you programatically send to external recipients using Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, email, microsoft-graph-api

I want to be able to send form an account on our Microsoft Azure Tenant as a user which exists within Entra.

I am trying using the graph api endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/sendMail".

I can send to internal recipients, but not external. When trying external, I get the error below:

> TESTING EMAIL Failed to send email. Status code: 404, Response
> content: {"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUser","message":"The requested
> user 'recipient@example.com' is invalid."}}

Is it even possible to send to external recipients using Microsoft as the provider? If so what is the correct endpoint or method for doing it?

Here is the Python code:

```
def test_send_email(request):
  #DOCs
  #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
  print('TESTING EMAIL')
  client_id = settings.AZ_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret = settings.AZ_CLIENT_SECRET
  tenant_id = settings.AZ_TENANT_ID


  user_id = "Info@aztechcloud.co.uk"

  # Microsoft Graph API endpoint for sending emails
  graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/sendMail'

  recipient_email = 'me@example.com'

  # Obtain an access token using client credentials grant
  token_endpoint = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
  token_data = {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'client_id': client_id,
      'client_secret': client_secret,
      'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
  }
  token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=token_data).json()
  access_token = token_response['access_token']

  # Prepare the email data
  email_data = {
    'message' : {
      'subject': 'Test',
      'body': {
          'contentType': 'Text',
          'content': 'This is a test',
      },
      'toRecipients': [
          {'emailAddress': {'address': recipient_email}},
      ],
    }
  }


  # Send the email using Microsoft Graph API
  headers = {
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
  response = requests.post(graph_api_endpoint.format(user_id=recipient_email), headers=headers, json=email_data)

  # Check the response
  if response.status_code == 201:
      print("Email sent successfully!")
  else:
      print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}, Response content: {response.text}")
  return JsonResponse({"Success": "Email sent"}, status=200)
```

The app registration has Mail.send permissions for both application and delegated.

Comment: Could you try the same via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and check whether it's working or not?  Also, please confirm whether your requirement is to send mail to external user from internal user(user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com) having active O365 license?

Comment: If you are trying to send mail from personal account, you need to use **delegated** flows like interactive or authorization code flow foe generating token. Check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225481/how-to-send-email-with-aad-graph-api-with-personal-outlook-account

Comment: It can't be interactive.

Comment: In graph I have to log in as a user which defeats the purpose as this is using a client secret for authentication.

Comment: Then you can make use of username password flow to generate token if MFA is not configured for users.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Azure platform, you should use the **SendGrid** service for generating and sending the SMS/email notifications to internal/external mail recipients.

SendGrid is a paid service, but very useful in enterprise grade applications. SendGrid offers separate portal as well to monitor the email statistics and other delivery reports with easy to use analytics.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of SendGrid. Is it not possible using Azure though?

Comment: yes, you can try the free or paid email communication service of Azure also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/create-email-communication-resource